What is the relationship between the zeroes of contiguous confluent hypergeometric functions?
Confluent hypergeometric functions differing from $F=_1F_1(a,b,z)$ by $\pm1$ in either parameter $a$ or $b$ are called contiguous to $F$. For rational $a, b$, assume I know $z_0$ is a zero of $F$. What is known about the relationship between $z_0$ and the zeroes of its contiguous functions?
For Bessel functions we know that in the analogous situation, $z_0$, being a zero of $J_a$ could not be the zero of $J_{a+1}$ because the zeroes of "contiguous" Bessel functions exhibit an interlacing property.
I'm retrying this question, phrased a little better. I haven't been able to find any information that I can interpret to be useful to me. I've looked at the big references - Slater's book, and Abramowitz and Stegun etc.
I think I want to be able to say something like "since $z_0$ is a zero of $F(a,b,z)$, it is not a zero of at least $F(a+1,b,z)$, or even of $F(a+n,b,z)$ for positive integer $n$ At least for large enough $n$."
I have read that there are a finite number of real zeroes of $F$ for fixed, real $a,b$ but I can't see how to leverage this yet.

see https://mathoverflow.net/q/477909/11260
